# Why does a @Query annotated method require a body?

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Spring.

I wrote a class:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class Kontroller
{
  @Query( value="select * from teszt"
        , nativeQuery = true
        )
  List<Teszt> osszesSor();  // <-- error
//.....
  @RequestMapping("/szam")
  public @ResponseBody String szamossag()
  {
    List<Teszt> sokasag = osszesSor();
    return("számosság="+sokasag.size());
  }

}
```

And it says (it = the IDE (STS), and at runtime when I call osszesSor()):
`This method requires a body instead of a semicolon`.

The Teszt class is:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@IdClass(Teszt.class)
public class Teszt implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private String kulcs;
  @Id
  private String ertek;

//getters, setters

}
```

It's a very simple table (that's why it becomes very complex in spring, because it has not a one-column key):

```
create table TESZT
(
    KULCS VARCHAR2(2000) not null,
    ERTEK VARCHAR2(2000) not null,
    constraint TESZT_UN
        unique (KULCS, ERTEK)
)
```

Comment: Because all methods of a class need a body. Only interfaces and abstract classes can define methods without a body. The Query annotation is supposed to annotate a method declared in a Spring-data repository interface. Not a method of a controller.

Comment: In the example at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query (2.2) findAllActiveUsersNative() seems like a method in a class. Why is it OK, and mine is not?

Comment: Where do you see a class in the section 2.2 of this page? I don't see any.

Comment: Where else can be a function definition?
Where should I write it?

Comment: OK, thanks, I see now.

Comment: The `@Query` is for Spring Data based repositories, they **cannot** go on just any class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I know.
I had to create a repo interface:

```
public interface TesztRepo extends Repository<Teszt, Teszt>
{
  @Query( value="select * from teszt"
        , nativeQuery = true
        )
  List<Teszt> sokasag();
//...
}
```

and autowire it in the controller.

```
  @Autowired
  TesztRepo dao;
//...
    List<Teszt> sokasag = dao.sokasag();
```

Not that complex.